# ASP.NET C# Eval not reading values out of db

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, eval

Help please - I have a listview looking up integer values from a db, then passes it to the codebehind to check if the db value is 0 - in which case it will display the appropriate message.

It looks something like this: On the aspx page:

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <ul>
     <%# List(Eval("p1", "Personal Info Verification")) %>
     <%# List(Eval("p2", "Medical History Part One")) %> 
     <%# List(Eval("p3", "Medical History Part Two")) %>
   </ul>
</ItemTemplate>
```

and on the cs page:

```
public string List(string input)
   {
     if (input == "0")
        return "<li>" + input + "</li>";
     return "<li>value not 0</li>";
   }
```

But it doesn't work - the 'value not 0' is returned even though the db record definitely contains a couple of 0's. Not sure if it has something to do with the db value being an integer and not nvarchar? Any suggestions or something else I could be missing?

Comment: Try changing your db column to nvarchar, because "0" is not the same as 0.

Comment: Not, sure about your code snippet.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe(v=vs.100).aspx
Here another params: container item + field
Or you just write fast example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Eval`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3d2sz789.aspx) also in codebehind on databinding(always true on `%#`). I would try to parse it:

```
private string List(string key)
{
     int input = int.Parse(Eval(key).ToString()); // note that the second argument is the format
         return "<li>" + input + "</li>";
     return "<li>value not 0</li>";
}
```

aspx

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <ul>
     <%# List("p1") %>
     <%# List("p2") %> 
     <%# List("p3") %>
   </ul>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution - I implemented this and the values are picking up as needed :)